# Get selected tree node item full path in C# (WinForms)

Tags: c#, treeview, selecteditem, treenode

I have a `TreeView` component and content of it like this:

```
MainLine  
  + SubLine1 
  + SUbline2
  + Subline3
  + Subline4
  + Subline5
  - Subline6
      SublineDetail1
      **SublineDetail2**
      SublineDetail3
```

Assume that `SublineDetail2` is selected and I want to get full path of it as string to a textbox just like this "(1.6.2)".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 8):

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode CurrentNode= e.Node;
    string fullpath= CurrentNode.FullPath;
    MessageBox.Show(fullpath);
}
```